# Event when updating input from the model Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive that I put in the input of type class.
I add the blur, focus event to know when I entered and exit the input to make the effect of the label (Material Design), but when I wrap the value through the angular ng-model I need to know that the field was filled.

Any idea?

```
app.directive('formControl', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      // Add class filled to form-control's that have a value
      if(element.val()){
        element.parent().addClass('filled');
      }

      // Any event here that can tell me that the value was changed by the angular so I can put the css class

      element.bind('blur', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        if(input.val()){
          input.parent().addClass('filled');
        } else {
          input.parent().removeClass('filled');
        }
        input.parent().removeClass('active');
      }).bind('focus', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        input.parent().addClass('active');
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: As you suggested, you can fire an event when the input is updated.

Comment: Yes, or that when being updated by ng-model I know that this occurred to be able to add the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the `filled` class inside the bind, you can add a watcher and add the class. Please refer the below example. Using colors in the classes to represent them getting added.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.name2 = 'hello';
}
app.directive('formControl', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      // Add class filled to form-control's that have a value
      if(ngModel.$viewValue){
        element.parent().addClass('filled');
      }

      // Any event here that can tell me that the value was changed by the angular so I can put the css class
      element.bind('blur', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        input.parent().removeClass('active');
      }).bind('focus', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        input.parent().addClass('active');
      });
      scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel.$viewValue;}, function(newValue){
        if('required' in attrs){
          if(newValue){
            element.parent().addClass('filled');
          } else {
            element.parent().removeClass('filled');
          }
        }
      })

    }
  };
});
```

```css
.filled{
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.active{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <label> The below input does not have required attribute</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label> The below input has required attribute</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="name2">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally if you want to show an error message like how you see in [`ng-messages`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.name2 = 'hello';
}
app.directive('formControl', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      // Add class filled to form-control's that have a value
      if(ngModel.$viewValue){
        element.parent().addClass('filled');
      }

      // Any event here that can tell me that the value was changed by the angular so I can put the css class
      element.bind('blur', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        input.parent().removeClass('active');
      }).bind('focus', function (e) {
        input = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        input.parent().addClass('active');
      });
      scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel.$viewValue;}, function(newValue){
        if('required' in attrs){
          if(newValue){
            element.parent().addClass('filled');
          } else {
            element.parent().removeClass('filled');
          }
        }
      })

    }
  };
});
```

```css
.filled{
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.active{
  border:1px solid red;
}
div.filled > .error-message{
  display:none;
}
div:not(.filled) > .error-message{
  display:block;
}
.error-message{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <label> The below input does not have required attribute</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label> The below input has required attribute</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="name2">
    <div class="error-message"> This Field is required</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked, but I need ng-model to be optional.

Comment: @RudáCunha I dont understand, I am not trying to make the input as mandatory, I was expecting that you were trying to make [this kind of input](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input), so I provided a way of adding the classes for focus and ng-model filled.

Comment: There will be input that will have ng-model and will have input that will not have. If I leave it as required it from error.